# WordPress custom field place in single.php

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax-error

I'm new at WordPress and trying to figure out how to put my custom field within the post and not before or after the post. I'm using this piece of code:

```
<?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'music', true) ) : ?>

<p><strong>I am Currently Listening to:</strong> <em><?php $key="music"; echo   get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true);?></em></p> 

<?php endif; ?>
```

and placing it just before or after While loop in single.php file. If I place code anywhere within While loop - I get this error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in
>   /public_html/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/single.php on line 36

In general, my custom field is working, just appearing too high or too low and not in a post. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `while` loop, you are already in PHP, so you can use this code in there instead (all I did was remove the PHP tag at the beginning and at the end, and reformat the rest so it is a bit more clear):

```
// ...we are already in PHP at this point, so we can go right into it:
if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'music', true) ) : ?>
     <p><strong>I am Currently Listening to:</strong> <em>
     <?php
          $key="music"; echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true);
     ?>
     </em></p> 
<?php endif;
// ...PHP code continues here
```

Comment: Oh, it was so simple.. working now, thanks! :)

Comment: No problem, glad it worked for ya :-)